# Jmeter - How to handle the license agreement in usage of script recorder?

Tags: jmeter

When recorded a script using recording controller and when executed, the response data in listeners shows only a pop up page for license agreement which comes in User Interface after login to the application.

License Agreement Page:

[image]

The next pages recorded as requests shows response data in tree listeners as 
response texts,

```
1|#||4|18|pageRedirect||%2fFunderMain.aspx|
1|#||4|48|pageRedirect||%2fDefault.aspx%3fReturnUrl%3d%252fProjects.aspx|
```

See in screenshot:Next responses Pages --

[image]

and also for some pages a response similar to license agreement page

instead of current page(refer screenshot for license agreement page).

So i have some response pages after license page which i am unable to view the User interface from the HTML response page data because of license agreement page interpreting .

How to overcome the issue of license page displayed on all other pages?

Note: The License Agreement page comes in the application initially only for the first time login of the user per user creation and as i have not logged in as a first time user it did not show me license page while recording the script using recording controller.So in recording script i did not accept the license agreement as it did not show me on recording it.

So add my question, how to handle the license agreement in usage of script recorder?

Comment: you need to look carefully at the network activity of the app (using Firebug, or Developer tools in browser), and see at which point the app decides that license was accepted, and how then it passes this information to the server. For example could be as simple as setting a cookie on accepting a license and then sending that cookie on each request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rerun the recording for two different pages.
Perform the "A agree" action and check the 1st call after that.
Compare the recordings for the two pages and you should be able to see the pattern. There should be a common redirect rule or a specific call.

And use cookie manager.

Reference:https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar